# "@" as a directory name on a webserver

Tags: url, directory

What (if any) trouble will I run into using "@" as the name of a public directory on my web server?
Example: http://domain.com/@/index.php

Would rewriting it with htaccess be safer? Issues?
Example: http://domain.com/at/index.php -> http://domain.com/@/index.php

Comment: Why would you want to do this knowing there *might* be issues. Are you that against using "public"?

Comment: Because the @ is important in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@` is a reserved character (`gen-delims`) under RFC 3986 section 2.2 and might have to be encoded.

If I were you I'd tell your marketing department no.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986 page 12

Comment: I figured as much considering we don't see it often.  I'm more interested in the ramifications.

Comment: Well there is no problem using @ as a directory name (at least on Unix). If it works for you, do it. Just CYA.